# Gintama Sex-Change Seiyuu Change

Tags: anime-production, gintama

Why is it that during the Dekoboko Arc (Anime episode 275-277) the seiyuu for Sakata Gintoki, Kagura, Okita Sougo, Kondo Isao, Sarutobi Ayame, and Tsukuyo changed?

Sakata Gintoki : Sugita Tomokazu -> Tomatsu Haruka

Kagura : Kugimiya Rie -> Ishii Kouji

Kondo Isao : Susumu Chiba -> Takahashi Chiaki

Okita Sougo : Kenichi Suzumura -> Itou Shizuka

Sarutobi Ayame : Kobayashi Yuu -> Okitsu Kazuyuki

Tsukuyo : Kaida Yuuko -> Hoshino Takanori

**Yet, the seiyuu for Hijikata Toshirou was not changed**. Why is that? If it was to keep cost low, then why not have everyone voiced by the usual seiyuu?

I'm not aware whether such sex change has happened before in other anime. If yes, then please state what anime and what kind of approach they were using and the reason for such approach for comparison.

Comment: Aria had an episode where one of the characters dreams about a world where everyone's sex was switched, but the voice actors didn't change; they just had the women talk in deeper, manlier voices and the men talk in higher, more effeminate voices.

Comment: My two cents: it was probably funnier this way. I haven't seen these episodes, but the very thought of a woman with Hijikata's voice is a real knee-slapper.

Answer (score 1):

It was done in jest; Hijikata's female form was depicted as ugly and swinelike, so they decided to keep his original male voice actor to make it even funnier. This is the most likely explanation, although there could have been some other reason like casting issues.